# C++ boost::regex_match strange behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-regex

Trying boost::regex_match and got a strange behaviour.

```
boost::cmatch what;
std::string fn_re_str = R"(\.sig\|\|([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\()";
boost::regex fn_re(fn_re_str);
if (boost::regex_match("{var d=a[c];if(d.sig||d.s){var e=d.sig||qt(d.", what, fn_re)) {
    std::cout << what[1] << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cerr << "not found" << std::endl;
}
```

`qt` is expected to be found.

Here https://regex101.com/r/iR9rW5/1 it is found.

Why boost::regex_match can't find it? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex_match` only matches full input: [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html)

> ## ⚠ Important
>
> Note that the result is true only if the expression matches the whole of the input sequence. If you want to search for an expression somewhere within the sequence then use `regex_search`. If you want to match a prefix of the character string then use `regex_search` with the flag `match_continuous` set

Use `regex_search`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9d5c9f4cd52c79e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::cmatch what;
    std::string fn_re_str = R"(\.sig\|\|([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\()";
    boost::regex fn_re(fn_re_str);
    if (boost::regex_search("{var d=a[c];if(d.sig||d.s){var e=d.sig||qt(d.", what, fn_re)) {
        std::cout << what[1] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
qt
```

Comment: ouch... just porting regex from perl and got confused by `=~ m/.../` `m` letter.